# Querying nested arrays in MongoDB & PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB with PHP's own driver and I have saved multiple arrays under main document. Structure looks like this:

```
{
 _id: 234234234324,
 accounts: {
    0: {
        enabled: 1,
        name: 'asdf'
    },
    1: {
        enabled: 0,
        name: 'gfsd'
    }
}
```

Accounts are removed and added by the user so I have no control over the array key. I need to somehow get all accounts that have enabled: 1. I tried array("accounts.enabled"=>1) but it doesn't work. And suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your schema accounts isn't nested array, it's actually complex object, because of this `array("accounts.enabled"=>1)` will not work (you actually can check only particular element -> `array("accounts.0.enabled"=>1)`).

Solution of your problem can be schema redesign as follows:

```
{
 _id: 234234234324,
 accounts: [
    {
        enabled: 1,
        name: 'asdf',
        id: 0
    },
    {
        enabled: 0,
        name: 'gfsd',
        id: 1
    }]
}
```

If you will make above changes, your query will work.

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't think it's worth the hassle to do schema redesign at this point. What I can do is to get all docs with accounts and then iterate and get enabled ones. Not very efficient but will work just fine in what we are doing.